# how to start a docker container along-with its parameters changed?

Tags: linux, docker, centos

I downloaded the official docker httpd container, but by default it maps my port 32770 to its port 80. i want that whenever i start the container, it listens on my port 80 -> 80.

is there any command line argument at docker startup to give or i can hard-coded this mapping in docker?

I tried to run it with "docker run " command , but every time it starts a new instance of it, and i lose my changes that i made to the docker container i want to use. how can i retain the port mapping changes?

Comment: You can set ports using the `-p 80:80` flag when you do `docker run`.

Comment: can you please give me complete command line? as i am new to dockers

Comment: What is the command that you use now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to publish the port from the container to the host, as [Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14955/thilo) says the `httpd` image already exposes port 80 so you can publish it.

This command maps port 80 and runs the web server in the background:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 httpd
```

Now you can browse to http://localhost and see the "It works!" page.

`docker run` is a shortcut for `docker create` + `docker start`, so it always creates a new container from the image. If you want to make changes to a container and preserve them, either use [commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) or a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) to create your own image based on `httpd` - preferably the Dockerfile, because it's easier to manage and automate. Then you'll have a custom website image that will always be the same when you run it.

Comment: As an alternative to making changes to an image, a frequent usage pattern is to mount configuration and content into the container from an external volume (another container or the host file system). That way, you can update the httpd image separately from your stuff. Which approach is appropriate depends on your requirements and deployment model.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own docker image based on the httpd official image. Then expose the port you want to map (EXPOSE 80) https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/expose it should do what you want.

It will give something like :

`FROM httpd
EXPOSE 80`

build : docker build -t test .

run : docker run test :)

Comment: That still does not do anything about the host port. In fact, the existing HTTPD container is probably doing this already.